# Change url using rewrite rules in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need your help with an issue I am facing.

I am trying to change the `url` from `domain.com/file.html` to `domain.com/some-text` using **rewrite rules** in .htaccess file. I just need to change the `url string` with no redirection.

How is this possible?

*Notice:* There is no `some-text` folder inside domain root folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a simple rules like this should work for you in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /file\.html[?\s][NC]
RewriteRule ^ /some-test [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^some-test/?$ file.html [L,NC]
```

- [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)
- [Apache mod_rewrite Technical Details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html)

Comment: I put, for example `domain.com/file.html` and it doesn't change to `domain.com/some-test`

Comment: Finally, it worked using these rules: `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /file\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /some-text [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^some-text/?$ file.html [L,NC]`. I tried to do the same one level down (for example: [domain.com/site/file.html] to [domain.com/site/some-text]) but in this case I get a 404 response (not found). Any ideas what is wrong? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: For doing this inside `site/` sub-directory, use `RewriteRule ^ /site/some-test [L,R=301]` and rest of the stuff remains same.